# Visual Studio Report not Exporting Correctly to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, rdl

I have a report that contains a calculated field for Completion Rate % using the following code:

```
=IIF(Fields!ORG_REG_OPENINGS.Value>0, 
Sum(Fields!COMPLETED_SLOTS.Value) / 
Sum(IIF(Fields!ORG_REG_OPENINGS.Value>0, Fields!TOTAL_SLOTS.Value,0)),0)
```

When the end user views the report on the browser, this calculated field displays as expected.
However, when it is exported to Excel, the column will show zeros instead of the expected % calculation.

Has anyone encountered such an issue before and do you know if it's an issue with Excel or Visual Studio?

Thanks, Denise

I tried exporting it to a different format (Word) and the issue resolved. However, it needs to be exported to Excel.

Comment: by default, the Excel export (render format EXCELXML) will output the actual values unformatted as long as you have not formatted the numbers yourself, which it appears you haven't so it should be OK. So if your expression resulted in 0.123 and the textbox format property (in SSRS) was say `p2` then the report should show 12.30%. When exported to Excel this should export as 0.123, the raw value. Have you checked that the cell in excel is set to the correct type?

Comment: HI Alan, Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, the cell is formatted correctly, and, inexplicably some rows are showing up as 0.0% when they should be much higher.

Comment: If you remove all formatting from the cell in Excel, does it still show 0? If that doesn't help, as a test, add a new column to your report with the same expression but no formatting whatsoever.